# How can I query a sqlalchemy relationship with an int instead of an instance?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have two models, Foo and Bar. Bar has a one-to-many relationship with Foo, with a "foo_id" column and a "foo" relationship. I'd like to query rows of Bar that have foo_id=1.

As far as I know, there are two working methods to do this:

1. Access the underlying foreign key column object: `query.filter(Bar.foo_id == 1)`
2. Get an instance of Foo, and do `query.filter(Bar.foo == instance)`

I'd like an alternative to these two methods that is more like `query.filter(Bar.foo == 1)` - that is, use the relationship column, and a plain integer instead of an instance. This currently fails with `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`

Reasons why I'd like to avoid the two methods above:

1. The first method isn't feasible in the real application because I don't know the name of this `foo_id` column - all the table metadata is generated by reflection and the column names are an implementation detail that I'd prefer to not rely on (they are currently wildly inconsistent and in the process of being renamed with alembic migrations, so dependencies on those names are undesirable)
2. The second method adds an extra roundtrip of a SQL query to fetch an instance of Foo before I'm able to do the actual query which doesn't use anything other than the integer ID that I already had (and the identity map doesn't have it cached with the way I use it). I'll admit this part is dangerously close to premature optimization, but still feels wasteful and there should be a better way.

Another way to phrase this question is how to reach the foreign key column starting from the RelationshipProperty, possibly using introspection

I'd also be fine with a way to get some sort of lazy loaded Foo instance which is enough for querying by ID but doesn't actually send a SQL query

Here's some self-contained test code illustrating the problem:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

def method_1(session, some_foo_id):
    """Works, but i don't actually know foo_id"""

    session.query(Bar).filter(Bar.foo_id == some_foo_id).first()

def method_2(session, some_foo_id):
    """Works, but adds a pointless roundtrip"""

    some_foo = session.query(Foo).get(some_foo_id)
    session.query(Bar).filter(Bar.foo == some_foo).first()

def method_3(session, some_foo_id):
    """Throws an exception, passing int instead of instance"""

    session.query(Bar).filter(Bar.foo == some_foo_id).first()


# database setup follows

Base = declarative_base()

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Integer)

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'))
    foo = relationship(Foo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session(bind=engine)

    foo1, foo2 = Foo(value=1), Foo(value=2)
    bar1, bar2 = Bar(foo=foo1), Bar(foo=foo2)
    session.add_all([foo1, foo2, bar1, bar2])
    session.commit()
    engine.echo = True

    for fun in [method_1, method_2, method_3]:
        print("\n---> %s (%s)\n" % (fun.__name__, fun.__doc__))

        fun(session, 1)
        session.rollback()
```

Output:

```sql
---> method_1 (Works, but i don't actually know foo_id

BEGIN (implicit)
SELECT bar.id AS bar_id, bar.foo_id AS bar_foo_id
    FROM bar
    WHERE bar.foo_id = ?
     LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
(1, 1, 0)
ROLLBACK

---> method_2 (Works, but adds a pointless roundtrip)

BEGIN (implicit)
SELECT foo.id AS foo_id, foo.value AS foo_value
    FROM foo
    WHERE foo.id = ?
(1,)
SELECT bar.id AS bar_id, bar.foo_id AS bar_foo_id
    FROM bar
    WHERE ? = bar.foo_id
     LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
(1, 1, 0)
ROLLBACK

---> method_3 (Throws an exception, passing int instead of instance)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asd.py", line 51, in <module>
    fun(session, 1)
  File "asd.py", line 19, in method_3
    session.query(Bar).filter(Bar.foo == some_foo_id).first()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py", line 304, in __eq__
    return self.operate(eq, other)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 175, in operate
    return op(self.comparator, *other, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1042, in __eq__
    other, adapt_source=self.adapter))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1369, in _optimized_compare
    state = attributes.instance_state(state)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way, `Bar.foo.prop.local_columns` is a property of the RelationshipProperty which returns a set with usually one item (for simple relationships like this one). Sets are unordered and you can't just get the first item, so `list(...)[0]`. Full code:

```python
def method_4(session, some_foo_id):
    foo_col = list(Bar.foo.prop.local_columns)[0]
    session.query(Bar).filter(foo_col == some_foo_id).first()
```